# iPhone crash that only happens on one phone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, symbolicate

I'm seeing a particular crash on one phone that I can't replicate on other phones.  I've copied the symbolicated crash file below.  Has anyone else seen something like this?  Can anyone shine some light on this?

```
Incident Identifier: D679377A-67D8-4601-91D4-FEDFD4C1D5FD
CrashReporter Key:   461dbf2d247a9faa589cea9165651af34e107a72
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         ThisApp [11984]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1C70C2B3-56F6-4FD7-8298-7E58818917B7/ThisApp.app/ThisApp
Identifier:      ThisApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-01-24 14:09:59.651 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52d4 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52c4 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52b6 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33be9d72 abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bdba20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347c594 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347b4c4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  Foundation                      0x33639910 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 648
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33a767d6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
12  CoreFoundation                  0x33a484f4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 188
13  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47e54 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
14  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
15  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
16  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e4a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
17  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e550 GSEventRun + 56
18  UIKit                           0x32099322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
19  UIKit                           0x32096e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
20  ThisApp                         0x00002458 main (main.m:14)
21  ThisApp                         0x0000240c start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b89974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c32b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd724a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x304df124 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x336465f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x33624192 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x3361d242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8168c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33a7f662 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a57efe CFRunLoopRun + 42
6   ThisApp                         0x00029afa +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4091)
7   Foundation                      0x33624192 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x3361d242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3eaf12e8
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x31bd9989      r6: 0x0029897c      r7: 0x2fdfea64
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x00292e80     r11: 0x3e5bec0c
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfea64      lr: 0x33bd52cb      pc: 0x33bd52d4
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x8efff +ThisApp armv7  <d754d3a20080db2f566f9694e3abe13a> /var/mobile/Applications/1C70C2B3-56F6-4FD7-8298-7E58818917B7/ThisApp.app/ThisApp
  0x183000 -   0x184fff  dns.so armv7  <fcefecb2d5e095ba88127eec3af57ec0> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe27fff  dyld armv7  <06e6959cebb4a72e66c833e26ae64d26> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30005000 - 0x30006fff  CoreSurface armv7  <f7caaf43609cfe0e475dfe83790edb4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x300bd000 - 0x301fafff  MediaToolbox armv7  <a18bbcc41a38917fe0ae5e183d3f6b07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x301fc000 - 0x302e4fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <1f478a71783cd7eb4ae9ef6f2dcea803> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x303d1000 - 0x30426fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <9365fc6cae1bff737257e74faf3b1f26> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30428000 - 0x30a10fff  WebCore armv7  <d6bd9cf88ee82ab6b0e33e0ae1190772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x30a28000 - 0x30ad5fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <3f2df600942dc72aad312b3cc98ec479> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x30bf9000 - 0x30c09fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6767a1e2afbc86a1ec63dd784f5d3677> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30c98000 - 0x30d57fff  CFNetwork armv7  <02fe0e30e54fffdcbbbd02e8cb812c3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x30d58000 - 0x30d60fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <854e82fe66feef01e54c7c8a209851ac> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x30e69000 - 0x30f52fff  AudioCodecs armv7  <be315c1e4982718460819fb240042952> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioCodecs
0x31266000 - 0x3129cfff  CoreText armv7  <b9b5c21b2d2a28abc47842c78c026ddf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x313e7000 - 0x313e9fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <8e6b0d9f642be06729ffdaaee97053b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x31451000 - 0x31464fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <855aefc263c6c20e6cf8723ea36125a2> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x314ad000 - 0x314b8fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <fabaddbcbc8c02bab0261df9d78e0e25> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31633000 - 0x31634fff  DataMigration armv7  <babbc72d4d48325de147d5103d7bc00d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3164f000 - 0x31788fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <657b327f2ceee9f22f9474f2f9bddbe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x317ce000 - 0x317d3fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <5f73c7138ee1cb7103a98aec99f9ed88> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x31947000 - 0x3194ffff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b29d4c5e300ef81060e38f72bb583c02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x31950000 - 0x31966fff  EAP8021X armv7  <36659ec2b9def7b5798a05327e369247> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x319b5000 - 0x319bbfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <5bbd9b3f5cfece328f80c403a8805ce9> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x319d7000 - 0x319dafff  ApplePushService armv7  <9d1eb7b11f0f146c941efbab2c055606> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x31a3f000 - 0x31a7cfff  CoreMedia armv7  <4ea4d349e886206d1ecf5bae870f3f04> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x31a97000 - 0x31b2afff  ImageIO armv7  <5b5a294d4250eff866fdbf891b1e8b34> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x31b40000 - 0x31b80fff  CoreAudio armv7  <f32e03ee4c68f0db23f05afc9a3cc94c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31b81000 - 0x31b96fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <ea156820997ae9a2baf664d0f79f18d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x31b97000 - 0x31be1fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <53a6e7239c3908fa8c2915b65ff3b056> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x31c9b000 - 0x31ca7fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <137b75e19b2450c234dec88d538798ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31cb8000 - 0x31ceafff  AppSupport armv7  <47c8055ac99f187174ca373b702ffa68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31ceb000 - 0x31cf4fff  CoreVideo armv7  <2092d5deb6b234e04678b7c1878ccd81> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x31d30000 - 0x31d37fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <71372c95d4af7af787d0682a939e40ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x31f68000 - 0x31f88fff  PrintKit armv7  <02a9c6f4173a0673c4637a3b570345cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x32059000 - 0x32061fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <6d6c62f52219d27be50f1d7c39a68dc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x32062000 - 0x323e3fff  UIKit armv7  <de1cbd3219a74e4d41b30428f428e223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32481000 - 0x32483fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <3f0b58ea13d30f0cdb73f6ffe6d4e75c> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3256d000 - 0x3261cfff  WebKit armv7  <644a1c6120578f896bed7121307aa2af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3261e000 - 0x3262bfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0f4e595e6eb2170aceb729f32b5de8c2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3262e000 - 0x32671fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <27ac7f05482a8aa9977150f34f9be6eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x32ac8000 - 0x32acafff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <e66758bcda6da5d7f9b54fa5c4de6da2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x32ad8000 - 0x32adffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <2989ea7a5cad2cfe91bd632b041d0ff4> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x32b0a000 - 0x32b44fff  IOKit armv7  <eb932cc42d60e55d9a4d0691bcc3d9ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x32b45000 - 0x32b7cfff  Security armv7  <cd28e102950634ae7167ddee9c686d36> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32bab000 - 0x32badfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1040629f37795146c9dcac8ab1a868fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32bae000 - 0x32e48fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <2e77d87e96af938aacf0a6008e6fb89d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x32e8a000 - 0x32e8dfff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a2af7147f5538d7669b14fa7b19b5a7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x32f24000 - 0x32f55fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <bb7ff9014b1dabec2acce95d41f05b59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32f67000 - 0x32f71fff  AccountSettings armv7  <19c79f81d5d55fe2e6b618fcdc28258e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x32f72000 - 0x32f7ffff  OpenGLES armv7  <a12565ffb5bb42e3019f1957cd4951d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32fc8000 - 0x32ffbfff  AddressBook armv7  <7c87e0175c8649d6832419da8a1cfac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x32ffc000 - 0x32ffffff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <3a385ed495379116abbe50bc8cd5a612> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x331c6000 - 0x331cffff  ITSync armv7  <87d409553f90e41a01afce047dc2e8fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x331d0000 - 0x3323ffff  ProofReader armv7  <d2e62a8ab7e1460c7f6de8913c703e6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x33393000 - 0x333defff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <251c5ac7380802a16e30d827c027c637> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x333df000 - 0x333e2fff  IOSurface armv7  <deff02882166bf16d0765d68f0542cc8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x33476000 - 0x33537fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <aaf5671a35f9ac20d5846703dafaf4c6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x335e8000 - 0x335e8fff  Accelerate armv7  <29dd5f17440bbb6e8e42e11b6fceda9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x33619000 - 0x33738fff  Foundation armv7  <81d36041f04318cb51db5aafed9ce504> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x33748000 - 0x33795fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <55038e5c1d4d0dbdd94295e8cad7a9a4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x33797000 - 0x337b0fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ee16b5cee12a8947c8e511ed51ae7fef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x337ff000 - 0x33837fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <374bd566263e8929c10d50d6a6a48a46> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x338e1000 - 0x33977fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <45665471fd70b0733b206d8166df74ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x33980000 - 0x33980fff  vecLib armv7  <e53d234e808c77d286161095f92c58cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x33a20000 - 0x33b06fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <01441e01f5141a50ee723362e59ca400> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x33b0a000 - 0x33b16fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <0099670dccd99466653956bf918d667a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33b43000 - 0x33b48fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <cec3f3271fc267c32c169ed03e312d63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x33b5c000 - 0x33c6dfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <138a43ab528bb428651e6aa7a2a7293c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33c95000 - 0x33d36fff  Celestial armv7  <b411f4662383ec24dbfbcde8f4c23d67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x33d6b000 - 0x33d94fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <54484a513761868149405df7fc29b5c0> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x33d95000 - 0x33d99fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e861a330d14702f148ca5133dcbe954c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x340c9000 - 0x340f8fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <3f982c11b5526fc39a92d585c60d8a90> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x340f9000 - 0x341a7fff  QuartzCore armv7  <83a8e5f0033369e437069c1e758fed83> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x341c1000 - 0x342e1fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <2d7b40a7baca915ce78b1dd9a0d6433b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x343c3000 - 0x3446cfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <b3d82f80a777cb1434052ea2d232e3df> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3451f000 - 0x3460cfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <c72b45f471df092dbd849081f7a3ef53> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x34613000 - 0x34625fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <cd2a699aa5036bdad0517603ba4db839> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x3464e000 - 0x34764fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <e7fbb2ac586567e574dc33d7bb5c4dc9> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34774000 - 0x347b3fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <a7c117c92607a512823d307b8fdd0151> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x347d9000 - 0x34855fff  AVFoundation armv7  <4c7356c795e01bd5c21b00a409a07476> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x34867000 - 0x34886fff  Bom armv7  <0f5fd6057bad5e1677869500d636821f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34887000 - 0x348c9fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <96d3af505b9f2887e62c7e99c157733e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x348ca000 - 0x348ccfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <30a5f1edcdb9ffe868a620199a4cbe12> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__NSThreadPerformPerform` line is the clue here.  Put a break point on all your `performSelector` calls, especially the ones that are `performSelectorInBackground`. Most likely you are calling a selector that does not exist on the object you think you have.

Comment: thanks for your advice!  i figured out the problem.  one phone had a corrupted address book entry that broke my application.  that's why this was only occurring on one device and not the other dozen that i'm testing with.

Comment: Just for completeness sake, the stack trace also shows that an exception was thrown. I future you could check the console output to see what the exception was.

Comment: @jasarien if this is happening in a production environment there is no console. Will those console messages get logged anywhere else?

Comment: There _is_ a console in production, it is simply a log file and can be retrieved. Check my UALogger tool for more info: https://github.com/UrbanApps/UALogger