# How can I resolve a SIGSEGV with crittercism

Tags: ios, objective-c, crittercism

I'm using crittercism to get crash report on my app. 
It's working pretty well but I got a crash with a stacktrace which is not really helpful.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x3b16c5b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation 0x33d6b0f5 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 461
2   CoreFoundation 0x33429683 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
3   CoreFoundation 0x33428ee9 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 213
4   CoreFoundation 0x33427cb7 __CFRunLoopRun + 647
5   CoreFoundation 0x3339aebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
6   CoreFoundation 0x3339ad49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
7   GraphicsServices 0x36f712eb GSEventRunModal + 75
8   UIKit 0x352b0301 UIApplicationMain + 1121
9   myapp 0x00024c2f main (main.m:14)
```

The crash is symbolicated but there is no information to point me at the exact place of the crash.
I think it could be an object released too soon, but since it's a random bug and I don't know where it happen its really hard to track it down.
How do I convert this stacktrace or the crash report to a human readable one?

Answer (score 1):

This crash is almost *exactly* identical with my main headache-causing crash at the moment, and I don't know what to do about it. The *only* change in my crash log is `main (main.m:6)` instead of your `main (main.m:14)`.

So far I've found this:

- [SIGABRT crash on __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214721/sigabrt-crash-on-cfrunloop-is-calling-out-to-a-source0-perform-function)
- [Rejected iPhone app has strange crash logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148756/rejected-iphone-app-has-strange-crash-logs)

***The accepted answers suggests that it could be related to misuse of `performSelector`.***

This guy also has the same crash, but with no suggested solution:

- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/24494

There are other, similar crash logs out there that have a curious addition:

```
...
CoreFoundation 0xXXXXXXXX -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + XX <- additional line
Foundation     0xXXXXXXXX __NSThreadPerformPerform + XXX
CoreFoundation 0xXXXXXXXX __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + XX
...
```

***Which again suggests that it's related to `performSelector`***, but that's still speculation.

Comment: What did the cause of the crash turn out to be?