# GraphicsServices: GSEventRunModal crash on iPhone

Tags: iphone, graphics

Been looking through crash reports online, and this seems to be the main problem.

Any idea what it is referring to? (Too many graphics, graphics are too heavy, etc.)

I haven't had any crashes in simulator or on device, oddly.

```
Crash log:
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52d4 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52c4 *_kill
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52b6 raise
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33be9d72 abort
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bdba20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347c594 _objc_terminate
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347b4c4 objc_exception_throw
10  Foundation                      0x33639910 __NSThreadPerformPerform
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33a767d6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
12  CoreFoundation                  0x33a484f4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
13  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47e54 __CFRunLoopRun
14  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
15  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode
16  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e4a4 GSEventRunModal
17  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e550 GSEventRun
18  UIKit                           0x32099322 -[UIApplication _run]
19  UIKit                           0x32096e8c UIApplicationMain
20  Definition                      0x0000247a main + 42
21  Definition                      0x00002410 start + 44

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b89974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33174 _dispatch_queue_invoke
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c32b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd724a _pthread_wqthread
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode
6   WebCore                         0x304df124 RunWebThread
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode
6   Foundation                      0x336465f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:]
7   Foundation                      0x33624192 -[NSThread main]
8   Foundation                      0x3361d242 __NSThread__main__
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8168c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33a7f662 __CFSocketManager
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a57efe CFRunLoopRun
6   Definition                      0x00013a34 +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] + 120
7   Foundation                      0x33624192 -[NSThread main]
8   Foundation                      0x3361d242 __NSThread__main__
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 _pthread_wqthread
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 _pthread_wqthread
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3eaf12e8
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x31bd9989      r6: 0x002cdf7c      r7: 0x2fdfe9f8
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x002d24c0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfe9f8      lr: 0x33bd52cb      pc: 0x33bd52d4
  cpsr: 0x000f0010
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `__NSThreadPerformPerform` is throwing an exception deliberately, something is wrong with information passed to it.  There may have been a nil pointer to something since the exception codes are zero.

One of these methods (or similar methods) may have called with bad information or the information is bad by the time it is actually run.

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: 
performSelectorInBackground:withObject: 
performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: 
makeObjectsPerformSelector:
```

Also, another StackOverflow article has nearly the same stack and that one was caused by a corrupt Address Book entry. ( [iPhone crash that only happens on one phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788155/iphone-crash-that-only-happens-on-one-phone) )